# image::RgbaImage::from_raw returns None

Tags: rust

I took a frame from my webcam with nokhwa

```
let index = nokhwa::utils::CameraIndex::Index(0); 
    
let requested = nokhwa::utils::RequestedFormat::new::<nokhwa::pixel_format::RgbFormat>(nokhwa::utils::RequestedFormatType::AbsoluteHighestFrameRate);

let mut camera = nokhwa::Camera::new(index, requested).unwrap();
let frame = camera.frame().unwrap();
```

Then I tried to do this

```
let image = image::RgbaImage::from_raw(frame.resolution().width(), frame.resolution().height(), frame.buffer().to_vec()).unwrap();
image.write_to(&mut Cursor::new(&mut bytes), image::ImageOutputFormat::Png);
```

And  got this

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src\main.rs:67:126
```

In the docs they say that it could be too small and too large but resolution is 640*480

Comment: Tried to do it with webcam 1280*720 but still returns None

Comment: You are assuming the frame's buffer format is RGBA. According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/nokhwa/latest/nokhwa/utils/enum.FrameFormat.html), the frame buffer can have one of multiple formats, but RGBA is not one of them. Try [`decode_image()`](https://docs.rs/nokhwa/latest/nokhwa/struct.Buffer.html#method.decode_image) instead.

Comment: @SvenMarnach please post that as an answer